# MySQL Not Properly Storing Ciphertext Produced from the PyCrypto Library

Tags: mysql, unicode, web.py, pycrypto

I'm building an application in web.py, but am having some trouble when it comes to storing encrypted data in MySQL.

PyCrypto creates cypher text that looks like:'`\x06\x7f\x81\xa0\xf4d\x00H\xef\xd0\x18[c\x18Z\xf8`', which when printed, shows up as " `ôdHïÐ[cZø`"

However, MySQL is storing it as: `???d H??[cZ?`
I'm storing it in the following manner:

```
query_string = "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (\"%s\")" % (table, column, value)
```

I tried using "`SET character_set_connection=utf8`" after connecting to the database, but it didn't yield any change in the results.

I'm obviously missing something very important. Any thoughts?

Comment: Don't you have to set a character encoding in the table itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL is trying to store your byte string in a character column. Because the connection character set is UTF-8 but the byte string doesn't represent a valid UTF-8 sequence, it gets mangled.

To get raw bytes into the database properly you need to:

1. make the column a BINARY type (or generally character type with a binary collation), and
2. use parameterised queries to get the data into the database instead of interpolating them into the query string where they might mix with non-binary (Unicode) content.

You should use parameterised queries anyway because the string interpolation you're using now, with no escaping, is vulnerable to SQL injection. In web.py that might look like:

```
query_string= 'INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES ($value)' % (table, column)
db.query(query_string, vars= {'value': value})
```

(assuming that the `table` and `column` values are known-good.)

Doing it like this also means you don't have to worry about the dollar sign.

The other approach is to use a normal character string, encoding away the non-ASCII bytes. You're doing this with uucode in your current workaround, but base64 would be a more common alternative that's easier to get to in Python (`ciphertext.encode('base64')`). Hex encoding (`.encode('hex')`) is most common for the case of a hash.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the great explanation. I had tried setting the column to binary, but I did not paramterize the query, so it continued to have problems. I will try what you've given me here!

Comment: This worked by using web.db.SQLQuery(['column', web.db.SQLParam(binaryValue)]) to create the query after setting the column once again to binary. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a solution. I'm not sure how elegant it is, but it was the best I could figure out.

ENCODING:

1) `import binascii`

2) `ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(plaintext)`

3) `asciitext = binascii.b2a_uu(ciphertext)`

4) `webpy_workaround = asciitext.replace('$', 'DOLLARSIGN') //if there are dollar signs in the text, webpy will try to use anything afterward, and will complain at you.`

5) Store webpy_workaround into sql.

DECODING:

1) Retrieve value from SQL

2) `asciitext = sql_value.replace('DOLLARSIGN', '$')`

3) `ciphertext = binascii.a2b_uu(asciitext)`

4) `plaintext = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext)`